# Writing an image Utopia book

Tags: publishing, book, artwork

Planning on writing a picture sci-fi book about Utopia.
The book will not have a plot (story), sequence or any conclusion. It will have approximately 30 illustrations generally depicting a search for Utopia, accompanied by minimal text for each illustration. Similar to a photo book.
Has anything similar to this been published before?
Could this spur sufficient interest?

Comment: It is a picture book, so yes, it has been done since centuries. It could "spur sufficient interest" if the pictures are interesting enough though, so it's not really about writing, but mostly about graphic story-telling, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you FraEnrico.
I see two options :

Option 1 - The illustrations in the book are placed at random. There are some visual recurring visual elements in each, but the intent is pretty much to deliver an accidental visual narrative.

Option 2 - The pictures are placed in some sort of chronological order, so that perhaps there is a sequential visual narrative (although still with no beginning and end).

Comment: Daniel - this answer was flagged as "low quality" - my guess is that this was because it was as much a series of additional questions as an answer. I've had a go at editing to make it more "answery". Feel free to reject what I've done, or to edit differently.

Comment: ... on the other hand, if you intended it as questions, it would have been better placed as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously no black and white, right answer, but in general I would say the artistic communities would lean toward option 2 - sequential visual narrative. Readers want to be taken on a journey so an accidental narrative, whilst making sense to you would probably confuse a reader who is unfamiliar with the premise you are trying to relay.

You mention a photo book, well photo journalism has been rising in popularity for years, whereby photographers use imagery to tell a tail, with limited if any narrative. This would make a lovely book both for adults and children alike, maybe look at some of the below links for sequencing and layout ideas:

[A photo book wedding album](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Storybook-Wedding-Album)

[A photo book travel album](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/explore/travel-album/)

[A photo blog trip](https://www.findingtheuniverse.com/)

[Scrapbook story telling](http://blog.creativelive.com/scrapbooking-storytelling/)